# Passing a AJAX Variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

Hi wondering how to send a AJAX variable to php,  I thought I had it but apparently not. In my console I get the error  "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation line 6"

Im taking it there is something wrong with my code straight after the alert?
(NOTE where it say "jquery" is in replace of $ simply because joomla does not like $ in scripts for some reason) 
UPDATED, Pay attention to

Script to click and get rowID

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function()
  {
     jQuery("tr.getRow").click(function()
     {
       rowID = jQuery(this).find("td.idCell");
       alert(jQuery(rowID).text());
       //Send the row ID to ajaxupdate.php
       jQuery.post("ajaxupdate.php", { submit: "update", ID_ID: rowID})
       .done( function(data) {
       var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       console.log( results );
       })
       .fail( function() {
       console.log("AJAX POST failed."); 
       });
     });
  });
</script>
```

Load first table(the one thats being clicked)

```
<table border="",th,td, width="500", align="center">
<tr>
    <th>TP ID</th> <th>Permit Deny</th> <th>Level</th> <th>Session</th> <th>Information Specialist</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($results as $row): ?>

<tr class="getRow">
<td class="idCell"><?php echo $row->TP_ID ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Permit_or_Deny ?></td>   
<td><?php echo $row->Level ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Session ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Information_specialist ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
<br>
</table>
```

Second table, the one that im trying to get to load

```
<?php
// In ajaxupdate.php file

if( (isset($_POST['ID_ID'])) || (isset($_POST['submit']))) //im Sure this part is wrong
{
$ID_ID =($_POST['ID_ID']); // pass JS var as a PHP var

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
->select($db->quoteName(array('CV_ID', 'Classifier', 'Value', 'TP_ID')))
->from($db->quoteName('sessionta'))
->where($db->quoteName('TP_ID') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('".$ID_ID."'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();


}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show your html as well?

Comment: wow! jQuery rules! there are 2 post calls. remove the 1st one and change ({ TP_ID: $(rowID).attr('TP_ID') }) to { TP_ID: rowID.text() }   and when we say post html, please post only the relevant html and NOT the whole web page!

Comment: Should it look like this now  jQuery.post("ajaxupdate.php", ( { TP_ID: rowID.text() }), function( data )

also now im getting http://localhost/abac/index.php/ajaxupdate.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Change jQuery.post("ajaxupdate.php", { submit: "update", ID_ID: rowID})   TO   jQuery.post("ajaxupdate.php", { submit: "update", ID_ID: rowID.text()})

Comment: I know this must be a bother now so my appoligies but when i changed it with .text() i got Uncaught TypeError: Object 12 has no method 'text' 

Is there any for me to send you my script and maybe you could see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

3425742,

I rewrote your script and tested it with this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthew1/LJTrc/). Try it out.

I see that you are using Joomla. Diving into Joomla as a novice is daunting. Within ajaxupdate.php the script is expecting to see a $_POST['submit'] variable. Either remove that requirement or add it like I did below. At the bottom of ajaxupdate.php add this line so that jQuery has something to test.

```
echo $results ? json_encode("succeeded") : json_encode("failed"); die();
```

Here is the jQuery ajax code:

```
//Send the row ID to ajaxupdate.php
$.post("ajaxupdate.php", { submit: "update", TP_ID: rowID})
.done( function(data) {
   var results = $.parseJSON(data);
   console.log( results );
})
.fail( function() {
   console.log("AJAX POST failed.");                
});
```

Edit "ajaxupdate.php" to the correct location of that file. If ajaxupdate.php is in a different directory you have to tell jQuery to look there. For example, if your $.post is in index.php in the root of your webserver and ajaxupdate is in the /js directory change "ajaxupdate.php" to "js/ajaxupdate.php".

Comment: ajaxupdate.php 404 (NOT FOUND)   << is that a problem?

Comment: LShetty, Matthew, with matthews code I get 
POST http://localhost/abac/index.php/.php 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:6
AJAX POST failed. 
which for the most part means its working but them stopping somewhere this may be an extremely dumb question but what does "ajaxupdate.php" do?  Just so i can have a better understanding. Also thank you for your time, ive been up for two days trying to get this to work

Comment: Let's say you are looking at index.php in your browser. When you click the row jQuery connects to "ajaxupdate.php," in the same directory, behind the scenes and gives it the variables "submit and "TP_ID". jQuery then starts to listen for a response from "ajaxupdate.php". Within ajaxupdate.php it starts up when jQuery sends it the variables and can grab those variables by reading $_POST['submit'] and $_POST['TP__ID']. ajaxupdate.php then does whatever its purpose is then echoes whether it succeeded or not. jQuery hears the response and tells you.

Comment: You get a 404 error and "AJAX POST failed" if your "ajaxupdate.php" file is not in the same directory as the page you are on. Joomla runs scripts relative to the site root so find where "ajaxupdate.php" is and change its location in the $.post. I edited the answer to give an example.

Comment: And you still have 2 post requests?

Comment: Your Edit explains alot i think my joomla template is missing index.php

Comment: Going to try somethings out ill keep updated soon, than you for all the help and please continue to help me (i need to get this done so i can sleep lol)

Comment: Okay so i think ive got it, well nearly. As i was confusing myself ive changed 
 { submit: "update", TP_ID: rowID})   
to { submit: "update", ID_ID: rowID})

Check updated question please and tell me if im calling ID_ID in the right way, remember i want to call ID_ID so that i can select* from table1 where TP_ID = (ID_ID)
Check updated answer, i think im going wrong when i try and get ID_ID from the script as i get this error  "Undefined index: ID_ID"

Comment: Problem is that ajaxupdate.php isnt a file. with joomla i am directly inserting my php codes and not uploading a .php file

Comment: The last bit of your questions has, "Second table, the one that im trying to get to load," see how the comment in that code block says, "// In ajaxupdate.php file"? The code in that code block is supposed to go into a single file titled "ajaxupdate.php". Cut that code out of the file you are working with, create a new file in the root of your website. Name that new file "ajaxupdate.php". Paste the code into that new file. You should no longer get the 404 error when your AJAX query fires. Remember: paste the code in my first code block into the bottom of your new file or JQry won't understand.

Comment: Yeaa Ive tried, Im still getting  http://localhost/abac/index.php/ajaxupdate.php404 (Not Found)

Comment: Oh actually what do you paste it in my first code block? 

So far ive posted it as <?php code here ?> and saved it in my notepad on the first

Comment: If you get time could you demonstrate what you mean, Ive been at i for hours trying and trying different things with no luck Thanks for all the help up till now much appreciated

Comment: @LShetty Every thing works now the console prints the rowID only thing is now when i try to pass rowID to php i get this 
Notice: Undefined index: rowID

Comment: line number? which line in your php throws that error?

Comment: I"m glad you are making progress. The undefined index error means that you tried to get 'rowID' out of an array like:
    `echo $testArray['rowID'];`
If the $testArray array did not have an entry for 'rowID' that error would pop up. Your script should not be looking for 'rowID' because when you passed the rowID you named it 'TP_ID' with this line in your jQuery ajax post: `TP_ID: rowID`

Answer (score 0):

you are passing `rowID` as an object, not as a single text-variable. You'd need

```
$.post("ajaxupdate.php", ({ TP_ID: rowID.attr('id') }), function( data )
...
```

Comment: It should be "rowID.attr('id')" as rowID is already an object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Now im getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null
also where you have id do i change to TP_ID ?

Comment: user: please post your html! assumption is the mother of all blunders!

Comment: Posted, abit a messy! But as you can see i load first  table then click on a row it gets ID, im then wanting to load another table where ID = ID if that makes sense. (extrmley new to coding I have been doing for about 5 days so sorry about my noobish/noviceness)